# Splitting string, ignoring brackets including nested brackets

Tags: python, regex, split

I would like to split a string at spaces (and colons), except inside curly brackets and rounded brackets. Similar questions have been asked, but the answers fail with nested brackets.

Here is an example of a string to split:

```
p1: I/out   p2: (('mean', 5), 0.0, ('std', 2))   p3: 7   p4: {'name': 'check', 'value': 80.0}
```

The actual goal is to obtain a list of keys (p1, p2, p3 and p4) along with their values. When I try to split the string at spaces and colons, I can avoid splitting at spaces and colons inside the curly brackets. But I cannot avoid the splitting at some spaces inside the rounded brackets because of the nested brackets.

The closest I got is

```
[\s:]+(?=[^\{\(\)\}]*(?:[\{\(]|$))
```

which is fine except that it splits between `(('mean', 5),` and `0.0`.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/VX1WvH/1, not every regex flavor can handle recursion.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Not trivial.
Note for Python developers: the standard module re does not accept such regex, but the module regex does.

Comment: Another PyPI idea: [`matches = re.findall(r"[({](?:[^})({]*(?0)?)*+[)}]|[^)}\s:]+", s)`](https://tio.run/##LU3dCoIwGL3fU3x4s30pZn8Ug/C6Z1gGo1ZKOsc2ozCffU3o6hzOr/n4utebEJrO9NaDVQ/1BukiIcTBERKz4nBa9oMHALPmwBjtlNQ0gx1mUORFBow6f4vCGnEObTjsZ9xyGKmWnaIc6LVW12fM0Jdsh1k5xOqUENJJH735yqr83uibbFtmE8HGipVcXCaMbMHKAktcpAKn6isuOJ0dr9IkA4eEGNtoz/5DGMIP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following PCRE/Python [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) compliant pattern:

```
(?:(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))|(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?2))*})|[^\s:])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VX1WvH/1).

It matches

- `(?:` - start of a container non-capturing group:

  - `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))` - Group 1: a substring between two nested round brackets
  - `|` - or
  - `(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?2))*})` - Group 2: a substring between two nested braces
  - `|` - or
  - `[^\s:]` - a char other than whitespace and colon
- `)+` - one or more occurrences.

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##LY/LasMwEEX3@YqLN5qJjfNqaRGUrPMNtgMmURLRWhKKXFxsf7srJ9nMwOHOHK77CzdrdtOkG2d9gFdX1S2C6gK@kLiNxGFl2wDAbSWIRKNqIzK8c4Z1vs5A4h7OEWyZ59BO4mPebxK9MHWjhIQ43dTpO2bEb/3TzuQzno7JwtUhKG@iySe0l1RSnMWRuErTgfYb5mXJPFDZP3g/PnlULUceimN5lxWn8Y/XJhCKLr962zpiXKxHB22effKLNmcdVfQyZpgbcgWepn8):

```py
import regex
text = "p1: I/out   p2: (('mean', 5), 0.0, ('std', 2))   p3: 7   p4: {'name': 'check', 'value': 80.0}"
pattern = r"(?:(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))|(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?2))*})|[^\s:])+"
print( [x.group() for x in regex.finditer(pattern, text)] )
```

Output:

```py
['p1', 'I/out', 'p2', "(('mean', 5), 0.0, ('std', 2))", 'p3', '7', 'p4', "{'name': 'check', 'value': 80.0}"]
```